# Permission Denied (public key)

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, permissions

I am trying to ssh from Linux to Windows with public key encryption. I am running a freeSSHd server on the Windows machine. I am unable to login even with the password authentication. Below is my error. Can some suggest a reason as to why this might be happening?

```
$ ssh -v administrator@xx.xx.xx.xx
OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to xx.xx.xx.xx [xx.xx.xx.xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/myaccunt/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/myaccunt/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/myaccunt/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: loaded 3 keys
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version WeOnlyDo 2.1.3
debug1: no match: WeOnlyDo 2.1.3
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug1: Host 'xx.xx.xx.xx' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/myaccunt/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myaccunt/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /home/myaccunt/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/myaccunt/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: Well, your public key probably isn't known to the server. If you want password authentication, you'll have to enable it server-side.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, yes i tried the password authentication by enabling on the server. But says again Permission denied, please try again. If you meant public key is not known to server: i actually placing the public key of my Linux under the freeSSHd/.ssh/ under the Windows.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how freeSSHd works. The expected file name would probably be `authorized_keys`. Is your file correctly named?

Comment: Yes my public key on the remote(Windows) host is named as authorized_keys. Still no luck. :(

Answer (score -2):

check on windows machine

1. Check the permissions of the shell (default,but check in `/etc/passwd` file)

   ```
   ls -ltr /bin/bash
   chmod 755 /bin/bash
   ```
2. Run the sshd service in one terminal ( check on which ID installation set up done)

   ```
   /usr/sbin/sshd -d
   ```
3. Run sftp/ssh command in another terminal

   ```
   sftp -vvv  userid@host
   ssh  -vvv  userid@host
   ```

Comment: You tell the OP to check on Windows machine the permissions of `/etc/passwd`??? Your answer seems conflicting.

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise, be sure you tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: Your answer is conflicting.  To the OP (@user2052801), the remote server (the linux one) should not have the public key named as authorized_keys, however should be contained in the output of the keys the contents should  have the public key hash and  (optionally the plaintext ip|hostname, or  hashed value of the same) when you run (on the linux machine) cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys OR cat /etc/ssh/authorized_keys depending on where your layout has the the authorized_keys file located.